# Leaflet.TimeDimension and Leaflet.Marker.Cluster

Tags: leaflet, clustering, timeslider

I am trying to combine L.MarkerClusterGroup with L.TimeDimension: basically, I would like to load a geoJSON and control the appearance and disappearance of points with L.TimeDimension, but in such a way that the points do not appear as individual points but are clustered with L.MarkerClusterGroup or using a different method if simpler. Have you ever seen anything like that? Can you give me some advice or refer me to some example?